# Css drawing - Custom nose shape

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I'm starting with pure css drawing and animations and I'm stuck at creating the shape of the koala nose.

[Koala](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGXR0.png)

I know clip-path can be used to accomplish this, but, how can i make firefox-compatible?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a lot of possibilities, but try the border radius

```css
.nose{
  border-radius:50px 50px 50px 50px / 100px 100px 50px 50px;
  width:70px;
  height:100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nose"></div>
```